# Can't install zbarlight

Tags: python, zbar

I'm struggling to install zbarlight (https://github.com/Polyconseil/zbarlight) on my Windows 10 machine since yesterday. The repo has some instructions about installing on Windows but they were not clear enough for me. Here's the stack when I try to install it:

```
C:\......>pip install zbarlight
Collecting zbarlight
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/3d/2111e8324d89d436bd3e361acfde556b71ef9ea6aedfa3a65c239cf4c287/zbarlight-2.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from zbarlight) (5.2.0)
Installing collected packages: zbarlight
  Running setup.py install for zbarlight ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\TestPC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2lgytakr\\zbarlight\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\TestPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-80xqch7d\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\zbarlight
    copying src\zbarlight\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\zbarlight
    running egg_info
    writing src\zbarlight.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\zbarlight.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to src\zbarlight.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to src\zbarlight.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\zbarlight.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[cod]' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'Makefile'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'requirements-dev.txt'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'run.py'
    writing manifest file 'src\zbarlight.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying src\zbarlight\_zbarlight.c -> build\lib.win32-3.7\zbarlight
    running build_ext
    building 'zbarlight._zbarlight' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\zbarlight
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-Ic:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include" "-Ic:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/zbarlight/_zbarlight.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/zbarlight/_zbarlight.obj -std=c99
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c99'
    _zbarlight.c
    src/zbarlight/_zbarlight.c(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zbar.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\TestPC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2lgytakr\\zbarlight\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\TestPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-80xqch7d\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\TestPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2lgytakr\zbarlight\
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to have visual studio. Do you have it ?

Comment: Yes, I do have it installed and I can see the cl.exe file in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx86\x86 directory.

Comment: Add zbar.h in the include directory

Comment: You can find zbar.h here: https://github.com/marmalade/zbar/blob/master/src/zbar.h

Comment: Ahhh Windows. I always wonder why people use it.

Comment: You mean my Python installation include folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\include), right? It's there and here's the new output:

https://pastebin.com/nN2nZJ6D

Comment: @Tim no i mean visual studio include directory

Comment: @Agile_Eagle, humm, Ok I moved it to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include but still the same output: https://pastebin.com/kUeuuzM3

Comment: + C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include :) No change

Comment: @Tim now you need zbar.lib in the library folder of visual studio

Comment: If you have brew installed you can use "brew install zbar" and after that pip install zbarlight

Comment: @Tim you can find zbar.lib at https://github.com/marmalade/zbar/blob/master/lib/x86/zbar.lib

Comment: @Agile_Eagle, unfortunately opying the zbar.lib file into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\lib\x86 and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\lib\x86 didn't help too: https://pastebin.com/31YuwtQr
I'm on Windows, so I can't use brew as far as I know?!

Comment: Is the error code same because the last time you said it was same, it was actually different

Comment: @Tim Is the error code same because the last time you said it was same, it was actually different.

Comment: @Agile_Eagle, I've amended the both of my comments, apologies about the confusion. You can see the full stack in my previous comment.

Comment: @Tim I am sorry but it still shows that zbar.lib is missing

Comment: @Tim If you have 64 bit you will have to open it in 64 folder instead of 86 one

Comment: @Agile_Eagle, this is really strange. The system is x64 but I've noticed that it's looking for the file in x86 so I pasted the zbar.lib there and in x64 as well but, as you said, it's still asking for it

Comment: @Tim Put it in all the lib folder and check it

Comment: @Agile_Eagle, thanks a lot for your effort! The project is quite big and I found multiple compiling issues with another packets as well so I decided to give a try with a virtual Linux Mint machine where everything works like a charm! I'm with a really tight timeline so I can't invest much time anymore. I think this should be fine solution at least in the beginning. Hopefully I will be able to figure out how to solve all of the issues on my Windows host.

Comment: @Tim That is great